Exercise: Show a property of moment generating functions
Definition
Let X be a real value random variable. The moment-generating-function is defined by
$M(t):=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{tx} dx$.
Exercise:

Suppose X,Y are independent random variables. Show that $M_{X+Y}(t)=M_{X}(t)M_Y(t)$.
Calculate $M_{X-Y}(t)$!

Approach:
Let $f_X,f_Y$ denote the densities of $X$ and $Y$.
By Definition we get,
$M_X(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{tx} f_X(x) dx$ and
$M_Y(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{tx} f_Y(x) dx$.
I thought of using the convolution.
Let $Z:=X+Y$, then
$f_Z(z):=(f_X \ast f_Y)(z):=\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x) dx$.
Now I need to show that $M_Z(t)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{tz} f_Z(x) dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{tz} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_X(x)f_Y(z-x) dx dx=\bigl(\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{tx} f_X(x) dx \bigr) \bigl(\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{tx} f_Y(x) dx \bigr)=M_X(t)M_Y(t)$.
But I do not know how to continue from here on.

You don't really need the integral representation. By definition,
$$
M_X(t)=\mathbb{E} e^{tX},\ M_Y(t)=\mathbb{E} e^{tY}
$$
which is given by the integral in case of continuous distributions.
Since $X,Y$ are independent, so are any functions $f(X)$ and $h(Y)$, in particular, $e^{tX}$ and $e^{tY}$. So
$$
M_{X+Y}(t)\equiv \mathbb{E} e^{t(X+Y)}= \mathbb{E} \left[e^{tX} e^{tY}\right]= \mathbb{E} \left[e^{tX} \right]
 \mathbb{E} \left[e^{tY}\right]=M_X(t) M_Y(t)
$$
as $\mathbb{E} (ZW)=\mathbb{E} (Z)\mathbb{E} (W)$ for any two independent $Z,W$.
Similarly,
$$
M_{X-Y}(t)\equiv \mathbb{E} e^{t(X-Y)}= \mathbb{E} \left[e^{tX} e^{(-t)Y}\right]= \mathbb{E} \left[e^{tX} \right]
 \mathbb{E} \left[e^{(-t)Y}\right]=M_X(t) M_Y(-t).
$$

What a elegant solution,thank you very much!
